# Get the output in the indicated format without selected data

Tags: jq

Using `jq`, how to get the output in the indicated format without selected groups, e.g. group_3. All data is to be selected from each selected group: name_x.

Input:

```
{
  "groups": {
    "group_1": {
      "name_1": {
        "field_111": "value_111",
        "field_112": "value_112",
        "field_11n": "value_11n"
      },
      "name_2": {
        "field_121": "value_121",
        "field_122": "value_122",
        "field_12n": "value_12n"
      }
    },
    "group_2": {
      "name_3": {
        "field_231": "value_231",
        "field_232": "value_232",
        "field_23n": "value_23n"
      }
    },
    "group_3": {
      "name_4": {
        "field_341": "value_341",
        "field_342": "value_342",
        "field_34n": "value_34n"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ouptut:

```
name: name_1, group: group_1, field_A_value: value_111, field_B_value: value_112
name: name_2, group: group_1, field_A_value: value_121, field_B_value: value_122 
name: name_3, group: group_2, field_A_value: value_231, field_B_value: value_232
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you fail?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want help with? Your question title focuses on removing data, but your expected output also has some transformation that you haven't really explained or specified. Ideally you would focus on one problem at a time.

Comment: @pmf, I am a beginner in jq. I tried various solutions, but they did not work at all.

Comment: @Weble, sorry for the imprecise question. Next time I will try to give you more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
jq --raw-output '

  .groups | to_entries[] | select(.key | IN("group_3") | not)
  | [.key] + (.value | to_entries[] | [.key, .value[]])
  | "name: \(.[1]), group: \(.[0]), field_A_value: \(.[2]), field_B_value: \(.[3])"

' input.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9oT3vBM6Kb)

If you want to exclude more than just one group, change `IN("group_3")` to, say,  `IN("group_3", "group_5", "group_7")`

Comment: Thanks @pmf for the solution. It works very well !